# This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration Paypal Sandbox

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

Todat I was integrating PayPal Pro API and i found this issue. I searched all of the stackoverflow and did as the suggested. I created sandox account, Then upgraded that to pro.

Can someone help me with this. I can provide any type of information you require.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is caused by either an issue with the sandbox account (not having pro, DPRP disabled etc.) Or that you are using live credentials pointed to the pilot server or vise versa.

I would double check your configuration:

To test PayPal Payments Pro in Sandbox, you will need a Sandbox account that has Payments Pro enabled, otherwise you will receive an error message.

Click here for information on creating a Sandbox account.

To enable Pro on a Sandbox test account
Click here to log in to your developer.PayPal.com account.
At the top of the page, click Dashboard.
Under Sandbox on the left side of the page, click Accounts.
Click the email address for the account you would like to enable Pro on.
Note: Only Business accounts can have Pro enabled.
Under the email address, click Profile.
Click Upgrade to Pro.
Click Enable.

If you have checked all of this please go to paypal.com/mts and file a ticket so we can research further. Please include the sandbox email address.